# Не могу создать агрегат

Tags: postgresql

Помогите написать агрегат подобный этому:

```
create aggregate array_accum (
    sfunc = array_append,
    basetype = anyelement,
    stype = anyarray,
    initcond = '{}'
);
```

за исключением того, что вместо array_append необходимо использовать array_prepend. Простая замена не помогает - появляется ошибка:

```
function array_prepend(anyarray, anyelement) does not exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё верно. `create aggregate` [требует](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createaggregate.html) от `sfunc` чтобы первым аргументом принимался `stype`.

Существующая штатно функция `array_prepend` объявлена эквивалентно такому:

```
melkij=> \sf array_prepend 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_catalog.array_prepend(anyelement, anyarray)
 RETURNS anyarray
 LANGUAGE internal
 IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE
AS $function$array_prepend$function$
```

То есть порядок аргументов не соответствует требуемому. Следовательно это - другая функция. Да, две одноимённые функции с разным набором аргументов - это две разные функции. А функции `array_prepend(anyarray, anyelement)` у вас не существует и вам необходимо сперва реализовать её.